# ModalNavigationDrawer doesn't totally collapse in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Here is the code that produces this strange behavior:

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            items.forEach { item ->
                NavigationDrawerItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding),
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = item.icon,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = item.name
                        )
                    },
                    onClick = {},
                    selected = true
                )
            }
        }
    },
    content = {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {},
            content = { padding ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Profile"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

I'm using:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha16"
```

This exact code worked perfectly fine before updating from `1.0.0-alpha15`.

**How to solve this?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you put the drawer contents into a ModalDrawerSheet it might help.

Thus:

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    etc
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: without wrapping composable in ModalDrawerSheet {} not closing properly